# Fastest way to compare string with pattern

Tags: performance

As far as I know I have these two options to compare a string with a pattern:

- Using the `=~` comparison.
- Using the `matchstr()` function.

So it looks like this:

```
" with =~
if string =~ "pattern"
    <do something>

" with matchstr()
elseif matchstr(string, "pattern") != ''
    <do something>
endif
```

I'm wondering which version of them is the fastest (or is there even a third possibility which is even faster?).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The operator version `=~` is most likely faster than `matchstr`.  This is for a couple reasons:

- function calls in vim script have a cost
- matchstr returns a string, therefore has an extra allocation

I've done a direct performance comparison.

```
let t = reltime()
for x in range(1000000)
    if matchstr('strpatingpattern', 'pattern')
    endif
endfor
echo reltimestr(reltime(t))

let t = reltime()
for x in range(1000000)
    if match('strpatingpattern', 'pattern')
    endif
endfor
echo reltimestr(reltime(t))

let t = reltime()
for x in range(1000000)
    if 'strpatingpattern' =~ 'pattern'
    endif
endfor
echo reltimestr(reltime(t))
```

Results:

```
  3.992500
  3.817862
  3.354163
```

The differences are marginal, but we can see `matchstr` is the slowest approach, `match` in the middle, and `=~` is the fastest.

Use `=~` when you need a binary output, use `match` or `matchstr` when you need the extra outputs or inputs provided.

Comment: I’d be interested in seeing `=~#`, too :)

Answer (score 5):

I've run @Mass bench against another one that avoids `:for` as I have the experience of extra costs associated to control statements.

My convoluted solution also does its best to avoid lambdas.

```
function! lh#time#bench_n2(n, F, ...) abort
  if type(a:F) == type(function('type'))
    let benchs = map(range(1, a:n), '[reltime()] + [a:F()] + [reltime()]')
  else
    let benchs = map(range(1, a:n), '[reltime()] + ['.a:F.'] + [reltime()]')
  endif
  let res = benchs[0][1]
  call map(benchs, 'reltimefloat(reltime(v:val[0], v:val[2]))')
  let accu = [0]
  call map(copy(benchs), 'add(accu, v:val + accu[-1])')
  return [res, accu[-1]]
endfunction
```

With the following on top of Mass' bench

```
echo lh#time#bench_n2(1000000, "matchstr('strpatingpattern', 'pattern') ")
echo lh#time#bench_n2(1000000, "match('strpatingpattern', 'pattern') ")
echo lh#time#bench_n2(1000000, "'strpatingpattern' =~ 'pattern' ")
echo lh#time#bench_n2(1000000, "'strpatingpattern' =~# 'pattern' ")
```

In the end, the results are a little bit more stable on my machine -- yet sometimes `=~` is a little bit faster than `=~#`, sometimes it's the other way around. And also, now I'm sure it's convoluted and not necessary: Mass' simple solution is more than enough.

```
" Mass' bench in order to have an a idea 
  5.726717
  5.520035
  4.839088

" Mine
['pattern', 4.724165]
[9, 4.75635]
[1, 4.313803]
[1, 4.557732]
```

In conclusion, yeah `matchstr()` is a little bit slower than `match()` wich is a little bit slower than `=~`, but honestly? I doubt you'll ever notice the difference, even when processing 100k or 1M tags. When you need `matchstr()`, or `match()` or ... extra services, use them. Otherwise use whatever you wish/prefer/like to test whether it matches.