# How to check if a string starts with another string in vimscript?

Tags: vimscript

I know I can use regex matching with `~=` and that `stridx(haystack, needle) == 0` does work, but if I just want to verify that one string starts with another, I don't want to waste resources checking the rest of the haystack, which `stridx` will do.

What's the fastest way to compare the beginning of the string? I have my own answer below, but I suspect it can be done even better, perhaps by not creating a temporary string but by directly indexing the two strings?

Comment: I asked a smiliar question: https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/29015/fastest-way-to-compare-string-with-pattern but I'm not sure it answers your question.

Comment: no, it doesn't, but thank you

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
fu! StartsWith(longer, shorter) abort
  return a:longer[0:len(a:shorter)-1] ==# a:shorter
endfunction
```

And the converse:

```
fu! EndsWith(longer, shorter) abort
  return a:longer[len(a:longer)-len(a:shorter):] ==# a:shorter
endfunction
```

You may also need contains:

```
fu! Contains(longer, shorter) abort
  return stridx(a:longer, a:short) >= 0
endfunction
```